# On Java happens-before relation, clarification needed

Tags: java, multithreading

It is said in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.

also there is said:

> Writes in one thread that are in a data race with reads in another thread may, for example, appear to occur out of order to those reads.

Does this mean that if `hb(r, w)`, then `r` must be prior to `w`, or that **if** `r` is before, then happens-before relation takes place?

Comment: This link could be helpful: [Fixing the Java Memory Model - Part 2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/) by Brian Goetz, Java Language Architect at Oracle.

Answer (score 6):

`hb(r, w)` means that `r` is executed before `w` AND `w` can see the result of `r`.

In the case of read / write actions, you generally care about having a `hb(w, r)` and want to make sure that the read sees the result of the write.

Example using a synchronized block:

Block `w` (writes):

```
synchronized (lock) { //lock is a final object
    aVariable = something;
}
```

Block `r` (reads):

```
synchronized (lock) { //the same final object
    System.out.println(aVariable)
}
```

`w` and `r` are synchronized on the same monitor, so there is a happens-before relationship between the 2.

Let's say that `w` is executed before `r`, meaning that we have `hb(w, r)`, then the JMM guarantees that `r` will print the latest value of `aVariable`.

Without the synchronized blocks, there is no happens-before relationship any more and even if `w` is executed before `r` (from a wall clock perspective), `r` might print a stale value of `aVariable`.

Without a happens-before relationship, it might even be the case that `w` is executed after `r` even if your program is written in a way that it should not be the case (i.e. the JVM might have reordered the operations).

A very good example of how weird things can get without a happens-before relationship is given in the [JLS - Example 17.4-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).